# Unbiased estimator - Poisson Distribution

Tags: statistics, proof-verification

Suppose that $X_1, \ldots , X_n$ is a random sample of size $n$ from a Poisson
distributed population with mean $\lambda$. Assume that $n = 2k$ for some integer $k$. Consider the estimator $$\ \hat{\lambda} = \frac 1 {2k} \sum_i^k (X_{2i} -X_{2i-1})^2$$
I'm asked to prove that $\hat{\lambda}$ is unbiased.

My try :

$E[\hat{\lambda}]=1/(2k)\sum_i^k E[(X_{2i} -X_{2i-1})^2]$

Then we compute $E[(X_{2i} -X_{2i-1})^2]=E[X_{2i}]^2-2E[X_{2i}]E[X_{2i-1}]+E[X_{2i-1}]^2$

As $X_1, \ldots , X_n$ follows a Poisson distribution I find that $E[X_i]=\lambda$      $\forall i=1,\ldots,2k$

Hence we would have $E[\hat{\lambda}]=0$ which is obviously wrong.

Can anyone point where is my mistake ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes $E(X)=\lambda$ but what about $E(X^2)$?

Comment: $E[X^2]=E[X]^2=\lambda^2$ in this case no ?

Comment: No. If $X$ is [Poisson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) with parameter $\lambda$ then $Var(X)=\lambda$ and $\mathbb{E}X^{2}=Var(X)+\left(\mathbb{E}X\right)^{2}=\lambda+\lambda^{2}$.

Comment: Obvious when you see it. Thanks for your help, I must have miscomputed my summation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is enough to show that
$$
\frac 1 2 (X_2-X_1)^2
$$
is unbiased; the rest follows trivially since it's just an average of those.
\begin{align}
\operatorname{E}((X_1-X_2)^2) & = \operatorname{E} ((X_1-\lambda)+(\lambda-X_2))^2) \\[8pt]
& = \operatorname{E}((X_1-\lambda)^2) + 2\operatorname{E}((X_1-\lambda)(\lambda-X_2)) + \operatorname{E}((\lambda-X_2)^2)  \\[8pt]
& = \operatorname{var} X_1 - 2\operatorname{cov}(X_1,X_2) + \operatorname{var} X_2 \\[8pt]
& = \lambda+0+\lambda.
\end{align}